# $(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) is not expanding in the azure pipleline build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, azure-pipelines, ios-simulator

I have build the ios-x86-64 build using the azure pipeline on the mac vmimage.

Now i want to run the unit test on that using Ctest.

I have given the following command in my .yml file

```
steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Run tests ${{parameters.platform}}-$(Configuration)'
  inputs:
    script: 'ctest -j14 -C $(Configuration) -T test --output-on-failure'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/out/build/${{parameters.platform}}-$(Configuration)'
```

After running the command my build is getting generated but on running above script i am getting the following error

```
Could not find executable /Users/runner/azure-pipelines-agent/_work/3/s/out/build/iOS-x86_64-Release/cpp/src/Microsoft.AugLoop.Client/tests/Release${EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME}/Microsoft.AugLoop.Client.Tests.app/Microsoft.AugLoop.Client.Tests
2021-09-20T19:33:32.6663830Z Looked in the following places:
2021-09-20T19:33:32.6665690Z
```

Comment: And what is `EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME`?

Comment: EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME for this should be iphonesimulator

Comment: My question was rather how do you set this?